# Is it possible to have an objectType within the same object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql, graphql-js

I've been trying to get it so I can put multiple "trainings" within the training type if since they would merge into each other once the user has both. However I can't seem to get it working and I'm stumped as to how to go about it.

Here is my trainingmodel:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let trainingSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  shortHand: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unqiue: true
  },
  desc: { type: String },
  office: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Office"
  },
  isMerge: { type: Boolean, default: false},
  mergeInto: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Training"
  }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Training', trainingSchema)
```

and here is my training object

```js
/**
 * Defines Training Type
 */
const TrainingType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Training",
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    shortHand: { type: GraphQLString },
    desc: { type: GraphQLString },
    office: { 
      type: require('./office').OfficeType,
      resolve: async (office) => {
        return await Office.findById(office.office)
      }
    },
    isMerge: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    mergeInto: { 
      type: new GraphQLList(TrainingType), // This is the error line
      resolve: async (training) => {
        return await Training.find({id: training.id})
      }
    }
  }
})
module.exports.TrainingType = TrainingType
```

Now obviously the error I get back is TrainingType is not defined, since I'm trying use something that hasn't fully been defined yet. But I've tried other ways like making a different objectType called MergesInto and then use it in the other. But that doesn't work either as one requires the other and one has to be defined before the other which will give me the error Is Not Defined. I can't seem to figure out how to get it working. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields` can be either an object or a function that returns one. Making it a function will delay the execution of the code inside the function, so you can reference the `TrainingType` variable without an error.

```
const TrainingType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Training",
  fields: () => ({
    ...
    mergeInto: { 
      type: new GraphQLList(TrainingType),
      ...
    },
  })
})
```